# Finding time index for result of Xarray aggregation

Tags: python, dataset, python-xarray

I'm running aggregation functions on an XArray Dataset with a time coordinate, such as,

```
ds.max(), ds.min()
```

Results are being returned, however, as this is a weather dataset, it would also be useful to know the time index of the return result. Such as the date the max temperature occurred in a given month.

Can anybody give any advice as to how to achieve this, as I can't find any info anywhere,

I would like to avoid having to search the dataset for the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for either `idxmax` or `argmax` and the like:

https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.argmax.html
https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.idxmax.html

Here's a 3D example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarraya as xr

da = xr.DataArray(
    data=np.random.rand(4, 3, 2),    
    coords={
        "time": pd.daterange("2000-01-01", "2000-01-04"),
        "y": [1, 2, 3],
        "x": [0.5, 1.5],
    },
    dims=("time", "y", "x"),
 )
```

`idxmax` accepts only a single dimension; in this case, it will the give the date of the maximum value for every (x, y).

```py
da.idxmax("time")

<xarray.DataArray 'time' (y: 3, x: 2)>
array([['2000-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2000-01-04T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2000-01-03T00:00:00.000000000', '2000-01-03T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['2000-01-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2000-01-02T00:00:00.000000000']],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
  * y        (y) int32 1 2 3
  * x        (x) float64 0.5 1.5
```

Searching the dataset isn't really a problem though -- it's a cheap operation, really, provided you don't write the loops in (unvectorized) Python:

This is fully general, works for basically every aggregate:

```py
time_max = da["time"].where(da==da.max("time")).min("time")
```

Note the final reduction (`.min` here) could be any reduction; there's no guarantee that there aren't duplicate maximum values in your array. This will pick the first one in time; if you want the last one:

```py
time_max = da["time"].where(da==da.max("time")).max("time")
```

And so forth.

This can be written so tersely because xarray automatically broadcasts da["time"] to a 3D array (with dims (time, y, x)), and then sets all the values to `NaN` or `NaT` with the `where` method. This obviously costs some memory, but it's unlikely that this is the most costly step of whatever analysis you're doing.